# Is there sorted data structure in JDK that supports remove at constant time?

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures

I have a task that constantly add  items into TreeMap, and 
it also remove just inserted items from TreeMap when some condition is 
met on this item.

I know the TreeMap's complexity is O(log-n) in both insert/delete. Since
the task had hold the deleted items all information, including: key, value
and maybe position information. If JDK has a data structure that support 
delete element with position information, the time complexity can be 
constant and reduce half computing time of my task.

Is there any one data structure support this feature, delete entry with position,
and other operations' complexity in O(log-n) in JDK?

Comment: A HashMap, with a good hash function, should be amortized constant time for insert, remove and get.

Comment: sorry, my question is not clear enough; I want to know whether there is a "sorted" data structure that did operation in O(logN) and support position based deletion thus can be done in constant time.

Comment: TreeMap implements a red-black tree. What do you mean by `position`?

Comment: for example, i call insert(kk,vv) of the DS and get a pointer to position. Then I can delete the previously inserted entry by this pointer at constant time, no need to search "kk" for deleting.

Comment: That's not really constant time: you need to do tree rebalancing, which can take O(log n) again.  If you don't, then you lose O(log n) for the other operations.

Comment: There won't be any position to track, it is a balanced tree not an array, every time we insert a key value pair, it will find its place by doing a binary search on key and put the element there and balances the tree accordingly. There is no direct data structure for this in java, you need to trade off between removal performance vs maintaining the sorted order all the times.

Comment: Oh, thanks. I forget that the Tree rebalancing still take O(log n) time after deleting. What if I add extra limitation, maybe that is possible? For example, limit the data structure to a fixed size and if exceed than pop out smallest entry when inserting?

Comment: @Houcheng, then you should tell us about what you are trying to achieve. What is stored, why ? ... This way we would be able to think about the best possible data structure for your application

Answer (score 1):

You aren't entirely clear on your requirements, but if the use case is to revert the last *n* inserts then a persistent tree might help. At each stage the tree is immutable and inserting creates a new tree with as much in common with the previous state as possible, so by keeping a reference to the previous state you can remove the inserted element in constant time.

You'll need to google for java implementations and they aren't in the JDK.

Comment: Hi, i thought the JDK is an implementation of Java SE? For example, there are oracle JDK and Open JDK.

Comment: @Houcheng yes, and it comes with a standard set of libraries. These include some containers, such java.util.HashMap<K,V>. The libraries which come with the JDK do not include a persistent tree map, so you will need to find a third party library or create your own.